# How to check the value in web.config of key-value pair and render different functionality

Tags: asp.net, web-config, key-value

I have created a key value (true/ false) in web.config, which looks like this:

```
<add key="Pass" value="true"/>
```

Now on my .cs file I want to check this value and if it is true show PASS button:

if it is false >> show the FAIL button.

I tried:

```
if((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pass"] == true)
```

But it gives error of comparing string with `bool`.

It will render two different button actions on its value. 
Also, should I create a single button and give different functionality based on value of key OR create two different buttons with different functionality and show/hide them appropriately on value of key.

Comment: convert it to bool : if((Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pass"]) == true)

Comment: thanks and what do you think about implementing   it on 1 button would be simpler or with two buttons  -@Zaki

Comment: @user43553 It's best to stick with one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

The value which you are fetching will be as string so it will not directly compare with Boolean.

So either you need to use true as string like below.

```
if((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pass"] == "true")
```

or

convert appsettings to bool as per Zaki's comment.